# Escaping double quotes in html attribute's value is good/bad practice?

Tags: html, syntax

**Syntax 1:**

```
<form action="home.html" id="frm-post2" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="text" required>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**Syntax 2:**

```
<form action=home.html id=frm-post method=post>
    <input type=text placeholder=Username required>
    <input type=submit value=submit>
</form>
```

both syntax are work perfectly, but which one is best practice ***syntax1/syntax2***

Comment: This is highly opinion based. But the developer tools in the browsers use double quotes, the specs use double quotes and most of the developers do so. So if you use syntax 2 you most certainly do something uncommon.

Answer (score 1):

In certain cases, authors may specify the value of an attribute without any quotation marks. The attribute value may only contain letters (a-z and A-Z), digits (0-9), hyphens (ASCII decimal 45), and periods (ASCII decimal 46). I recommend using quotation marks even when it is possible to eliminate them.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax 1 is "correct".

Many thinks work in HTML, however, kinda everyone uses double quotes. You don't have do use them but everyone does.

Comment: Why do you think that syntax 2 is not valid html? In html attribute values only have to be quoted if they contain certain characters.

Comment: W3C says syntax 2 isn't valid html.

Comment: Where does w3c claim that? Those attribute values are valid according to the [unquoted attribute-value syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120320/syntax.html#attr-value-unquoted)